# Calling constructor inside a method

Tags: php, constructor

Somehow my mind went far away from the current problem and I made a terrible mistake..
I called a parent constructor inside a method that just initializes classes properties.. Or did I.. The parent constructor's job was to set the ID value. Well PHP allowed me to do that. But isnt that just wrong? And it looks like I can call classes own constructor in the same way.. Isn't it that constructors should only be allowed to call when creating instances of a class... And they are only called when creating instances..

```
<?php

    class A {

        public function __construct() {
            echo "Test<br />";
        }

    }

    class B extends A {

        public function test() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

    }

    $b = new B();
    $b->test();

    // OUTPUT:
    // Test
    // Test

?>
```

EDIT: So the conclusion is that PHP allows you to call the constructor inside a method but it actually does nothing. And that other "TEST" string comes from the base class's constructor.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will cause implode(",", $theInterwebs)

Comment: Morally, it is definitely wrong. Just don't do it.

Comment: It is just funny when you do stuff in a hurry and then realize that what is happening is very weird. :)

Comment: The constructor is just a glorified initialization method. There's no harm in calling it (again), unless it does something crazy.

Comment: Note there is a difference between [normative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normative) statements ("should", "shouldn't") and descriptive statements ("does", "doesn't", "is" "isn't", "can", "can't"). You shouldn't call constructors in PHP, unless it's from an overriding constructor, but you can.

Comment: "So the conclusion is that PHP allows you to call the constructor inside a method but it actually does nothing". No. It actually doesn't "does nothing", but does what it's supposed to do. I have a constructor with variable number of params; I instantiate an object calling the constructor with one param, and later I call a certain method which calls the constructor with different parameters (number of them and values), initializing some other attributes of the object, leaving intact the untouched ones / previously initialized in the "original" construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One word describes the situation exactly.

**Override**

What happens is that when the parent has a method such as a `__construct` and the child class does not have that method, when the method is called on the child class it calls the parents method.

For example:

```
class Parent
{
     public function start(){}
}
class Child extends Parent
{

}
```

if I call the the start method on the Child class its executes the `Parent::Start()`, but if Child class has a method called `Start()` that one would be called as its **Overriding** the parents version.

Every class has a constructor method, and php executes that to compile the class into an object, now if you have a method called `__construct()` in a class, PHP Calls the internal construct which compiles the class, and then calls your override constructor.

If you do not have a `__construct` method in the Child class PHP executes the parent `__construct`

This is the reason why you get **2** x `Test` in your Object initialization.

The only time you should be using `parent:__cosntruct()` is if your Child class requires a user defined constructor, you explicitly call the parent construct to prepare the parent object.

For example:

```
class Parent
{
     public function __construct()
     {
         //Do work on Parent Class
     }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public function __construct()
    {
         //Do Work on Child Class

         parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

The reason you should only ever call a parent constructor within a child constructor and not a child method is that constructors should only ever be called once, this way enforces that.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Well for now on I try not to lose the focus. :) Somehow I'm in this level where I`m questioning everyting even the simplest and most basic things like these. And somehow I need someone to say it to me what is right and what is wrong.

Comment: well education is someone transferring knowledge on to you, so if you ask then you educate faster, there's nothing wrong with it, and im glad to help out.

Comment: Yes, and thanks! Sometimes I just found myself questioning things that I think I already know.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call a parent constructor at arbitrary times. You call a parent constructor only from a child constructor, i.e. whilst the object is being constructed.

If *php* allows otherwise, then that's simply an artefact of how classes are implemented in the language, and should not be taken to mean that it's ever a good thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice, and well-behaved OOP languages usually do not let you do that. Although it is totally OK if you know exactly what you're doing. (And you can document that so other programmers working with that code understand your concept).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an "init" method to handle this kind of behavior. Here is an example:

```
class A {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->init();
    }
    protected function init() {
        echo "Test<br />";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        // suppress parent constructor 
    }
    public function test() {
        $this->init();
    }
}
```